# google mock with boost::test causes memory leak

Tags: c++, boost, memory-leaks, googlemock, boost-unit-test-framework

I am trying to create unit tests using boost::test and google mock.
Adding a call to InitGoogleMock causes boost to signal some memory leaks. I searched for some sort of "DeInitGoogleMock" but didn't find any.

Why does this memory leak come up? How can it be fixed?

main.cpp:

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE my_testt
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

struct InitGMock {
  InitGMock() {
    ::testing::GTEST_FLAG(throw_on_failure) = true;
    //::testing::InitGoogleMock(&boost::unit_test::framework::master_test_suite().argc,
    //  boost::unit_test::framework::master_test_suite().argv);
  }

  ~InitGMock() { }
};

BOOST_GLOBAL_FIXTURE(InitGMock);

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( test_case )
{
  BOOST_CHECK( true );
}
```

Output:

```
Running 1 test case...
*** No errors detected
```

Output after uncommenting the InitGoogleMock lines:

```
Running 1 test case...
*** No errors detected
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{669} normal block at 0x00B4E700, 48 bytes long.
 Data: <                > 00 E7 B4 00 00 E7 B4 00 00 E7 B4 00 CD CD CD CD
{668} normal block at 0x00B473B0, 28 bytes long.
 Data: <                > 00 00 00 00 CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD
{667} normal block at 0x00B471B8, 24 bytes long.
 Data: <                > FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Object dump complete.
```

Comment: Is there a justified reason to use boost::test instead of googletest? If you are already planning to use googlemock, using anything other than googletest is a poor choice. You will constantly run into issues which will require workarounds (https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/ForDummies.md#using-google-mock-with-any-testing-framework). Save yourself time and nerves and decide either to use boost::test with some other mocking framework or googletest/googlemock combo.

Comment: Unfortunately I am constrained to use boost::test for this project :(. Google mock was the one that got the most recommendations (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759560/boosttest-and-mocking-framework and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604549/mocking-with-boosttest )... Would you suggest using any other? (I also had a look on hippo mocks and mockitopp)

Comment: As you can see in selected answer (your first link), even the person that recommends googlemock says he ended up using googletest. As far as the recommendation goes, I did not try out all other mock frameworks but I remember I liked how FakeIt was easy to use. Plus, it was header only.

Comment: Thank you! I just came across Turtle (http://turtle.sourceforge.net/ ) and it seems to be the right choice to go along with boost::test...